# Ender 3 loss of power

Tags: creality-ender-3, extruder, bigtreetech

I have a Sprite Pro extruder kit with the BTT SKR Mini E3 screen bundle. When I plug in the Sprite Pro, the entire board shuts off. What do I need to do? I have tried to switch the wires.

Comment: Check everything again?  If the PSU shuts off completely, it's because of a short circuit.  Don't assume wire colours are correct.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like there might be a short circuit occurring when you plug in the Sprite Pro extruder kit, causing the entire board to shut off.

Check the wiring: Ensure that the wiring connections between the extruder kit and the screen are correct and secure. Double-check the wiring diagrams for both components to ensure that you have connected them correctly.

Check for shorts: Use a multimeter on continuity mode to check for any shorts in the wiring.